# TypeScript Resolve right Namspace failed

Tags: javascript, typescript

I've the problem that I'am using some external libs which has nearly equal namespaces like:

```
declare module Test.Internal.Blubb {
   interface IAnzeige {
      Option: Internal.AnzeigeOptionen.IAnzeigeOptionen;
   }

}

declare module Internal.AnzeigeOptionen {
     interface IAnzeigeOptionen {
        AnzeigeX: number;
        AnzeigeY: number;
     }
}
```

and this code will not compile because it's showing the error:

`Test.Internal` has no exported member `AnzeigeOptionen`

the row:

```
Option: Internal.AnzeigeOptionen.IAnzeigeOptionen;
```

shows this error.

Is there a way to bypass this Problem?

I'm using TypeScript 1.4 and VS 2013 Update 4

Comment: Have you tried exporting IAnzeigeOptionen? __`export`__ `interface IAnzeigeOptionen`

Comment: No Export doesn't help - same error

Comment: See [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/983) - no way to reference the global namespace in TypeScript.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the code is that when the compiler sees line `Internal.AnzeigeOptionen`, it tries to resolve `Internal` as `Test.Internal` due to namespace collision.

You can re-import the `Internal` module with another name outside your `Test.Internal` declaration.

```
import m = Internal;
declare module Test.Internal.Blubb {
    interface IAnzeige {
        Option: m.AnzeigeOptionen.IAnzeigeOptionen;
    }
}

declare module Internal.AnzeigeOptionen {
    interface IAnzeigeOptionen {
        AnzeigeX: number;
        AnzeigeY: number;
    }
}
```